# _TCHAR* argv[] to wstring

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, argv, wstring

I would like to convert a argv to wstring.

I tried

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wstring sStartDir=L"";

    if (argc==1)
    {
            //no params given
    }
    else
    {
        sStartDir=argv[1];
    }
```

but the compiler said "No = operator compatible with this operand".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the language set to "Use unicode", and now it works.